# How to label data points in matplotlib scatter plot while looping through pandas dataframes?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, label, scatter-plot

I have a pandas dataframe including the following columns:

```
label = ('A' , 'D' , 'K', 'L', 'P')
x = (1 , 4 , 9, 6, 4)
y = (2 , 6 , 5, 8, 9)
plot_id = (1 , 1 , 2, 2, 3)
```

I want to creat 3 seperate scatter plots - one for each individual `plot_id`.  So the first scatter plot should consists all entries where `plot_id == 1` and hence the points (1,2) and (4,6). Each data point should be labelled by `label`. Hence the first plot should have the labels `A`and `B`.

I understand I can use `annotate` to label, and I am familiar with `for` loops. But I have no idea how to combine the two.

I wish I could post better code snippet of what I have done so far - but it's just terrible. Here it is:

```
for i in range(len(df.plot_id)):
    plt.scatter(df.x[i],df.y[i])
    plt.show()
```

That's all I got - unfortunately. Any ideas on how to procede?

Comment: what is the link between `plot_id` and `label` ?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question while commented. I basically am trying to make 3 plots  - for each individual `plot_id`.

Comment: then `label` column is useless ...

Comment: No. I want to label/annotate the data entries (or glyphs if you will) with `label`.

Comment: You need to be very precise about the following: How many plots do you want to create? How many points do you want each plot to have? Where should the labels appear in the plot? Is it correct that you want to have exactly one point per plot?

Comment: Sorry. I edited the question above. Do I make myself understandable?

Comment: how many different `plot_ids` do you have ? If it's a small number you can do some subplots.

Comment: I have 54. how would that work?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***updated answer***
save separate image files

```
def annotate(row, ax):
    ax.annotate(row.label, (row.x, row.y),
                xytext=(10, -5), textcoords='offset points')

for pid, grp in df.groupby('plot_id'):
    ax = grp.plot.scatter('x', 'y')
    grp.apply(annotate, ax=ax, axis=1)
    plt.savefig('{}.png'.format(pid))
    plt.close()
```

***1.png***
[image]

***2.png***
[image]

***3.png***
[image]

***old answer***
for those who want something like this

```
def annotate(row, ax):
    ax.annotate(row.label, (row.x, row.y),
                xytext=(10, -5), textcoords='offset points')

fig, axes = plt.subplots(df.plot_id.nunique(), 1)
for i, (pid, grp) in enumerate(df.groupby('plot_id')):
    ax = axes[i]
    grp.plot.scatter('x', 'y', ax=ax)
    grp.apply(annotate, ax=ax, axis=1)
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

***setup***

```
label = ('A' , 'D' , 'K', 'L', 'P')
x = (1 , 4 , 9, 6, 4)
y = (2 , 6 , 5, 8, 9)
plot_id = (1 , 1 , 2, 2, 3)

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(label=label, x=x, y=y, plot_id=plot_id))
```

Comment: since there are 54 `plot_ids`, I don't think subplots might be a good idea.  am I wrong ?

Comment: I'm sorry, you weren't clear.  You said you wanted separate plots.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I need 54 individual plots. I will try to be more clear next time!

Comment: Great solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a **simple way** to deal with your problem :

```
zipped = zip(zip(zip(df.x, df.y), df.plot_id), df.label)
# Result : [(((1, 2), 1), 'A'),
#           (((4, 6), 1), 'D'),
#           (((9, 5), 2), 'K'),
#           (((6, 8), 2), 'L'),
#           (((4, 9), 3), 'P')]
```

To retrieve the positions, the plot index and the labels, you can loop as below :

```
for (pos, plot), label in zipped:
    ...
    print pos
    print plot
    print label
```

Now here is what you can do in your case :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for (pos, plot), label in zipped:
    plt.figure(plot)
    x, y = pos
    plt.scatter(x, y)
    plt.annotate(label, xy=pos)
```

It will create as much figures as `plot_ids` and for each figure display the scatter plot of the points with the corresponding `plot_ids` value. What's more it overlays the label on each point.

Comment: Wow! This is great! Is there a way to save the plots on the loop too? I tried to adapt the code and save but unfortunately replace too...

Comment: I get a figure for each `pos` . So given the example brought forward, I get 6 figures. How do I combine them into 3?

Comment: @Rachel Are you sure that you get a figure for each `pos` ? It works perfectly for me ...

Comment: Yes. Your print command suggests you use Python 2 whilst I use python 3? Maybe that's why?

Comment: can you edit your question with your new piece of code and the variables you use ? I'll check it out

Comment: I copied your code exactly (I always do, before applying it to my own code). I do indeed get a figure for each `pos`. Strange! Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is a function to create these plots (based on @piRSquared answer)

```
def plotter2(data,x,y,grp,lbl):

    def annotate(row, ax):
       ax.annotate(row[lbl], (row[x], row[y]),
            xytext=(3, 0), textcoords='offset points')

   for pid, grp in data.groupby(grp):
       ax = grp.plot.scatter(x, y)
       grp.apply(annotate, ax=ax, axis=1)
       plt.show()
       plt.savefig('{}.png'.format(pid))
```