# Sort dataframe by new index after grouping in pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I need to sort my data frame by dates recorded as strings so when I plot my values the dates are plotted in order. I grouped it by date `grouped = datanew.groupby(['Date']).sum()` so `sort_values('Date')` doesn't work. I tried this

`grouped = datanew.sort_values(by='Date',ascending=False).groupby('Date').sum()`

I also tried this:

```
date = sort.reset_index()
sortd = date.sort_values(by='Date', ascending=False)
```

but in this case, it sorts my df by index not by 'Date' which puzzles me.

Will appreciate your help.

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) + [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) + [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html) + [`plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%d_%b')
df = df.sort_index()
df.index = df.index.strftime('%d_%b')
df.plot()
```

Sample:

```
np.random.seed(10)
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[3,5,6,1]}, index=['11_May','12_May','1_May', '2_May'])
print (df)
        a
11_May  3
12_May  5
1_May   6
2_May   1

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%d_%b')
df = df.sort_index()
df.index = df.index.strftime('%d_%b')
print (df)
        a
01_May  6
02_May  1
11_May  3
12_May  5

df.plot()
```

[image: graph]

Comment: Done! :) Thank you.

Comment: hi! I hope you can help me a little further with my plot. Now I have a problem adding an annotation. I get this error: `ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 10_May` when trying to access index: `plt.annotate('Peak',
             (grouped.index[9], grouped['L'][9]),
             xytext=(15, 15), 
             textcoords='offset points',
             arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='-|>'))` I thought that setting index `to_datetime` and then `strftime` solved the problem, but pandas still expects it to be a float...

Comment: what return `grouped.index[9]` and what `grouped.index['L'][9]` ? Second seems a bit weird.

Comment: `grouped.index[9]` returns u'10_May' while `grouped['L'][9]` returns 10.0. I'm just trying to locate the point on the graph to add the annotation.

Comment: hmmm, do you think something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41481243/2901002) ? I think the best is create new question - not sure if I know to help, because my knowledge of matplotlib is only basic. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you anyway! Will explore further.